# How to read a .txt file from S3 and use the resulting dataframe as a SQL query in pyspark

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, dataframe, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have a txt file saved in a s3 folder. the content of that text file looks like:

```
select 
fiscal year, 
fiscal quarter,
refresh time,
...
from table 1
where condition1 and condition2.
```

I can use the following codes to read that file,

```
hist_sql=spark.read.text('s3://team-test/history/sql/his.txt)
```

but the file is read into a spark dataframe,

Instead, I want to convert that 'hist_sql' dataframe to a sql query like below in spark,

```
sql="""
select 
fiscal year, 
fiscal quarter,
refresh time,
...
from table 1
where condition1 and condition2
"""
```

so I can feed the above sql query to the following codes and query a redshift database

```
df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
    .option("url", jdbcUrl)\
    .option("query", sql )\
    .option("forward_spark_s3_credentials", True)\
    .load()
```

can someone show the codes to do it? thanks

Comment: Dataframe has a to_string function see the details here, https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-text-file-rdd-dataframe/

Answer (score 0):

try this hope its work for you

```
    sql="""
select 
fiscal year, 
fiscal quarter,
refresh time,
...
from table 1
where condition1 and condition2
""" 
df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift").option("url", "jdbc:redshift://<red shift path>:<portno>/<dbname?).option("dbtable","<db_table>").option("user","<username>").option("password","<password>").option("query", sql).option("tempdir", "s3a://<location>").load()
df.show()
```

or another way you can use by read by aws s3 data consider as df2

```
    conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0')
conf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider')
conf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key', <access_key>)
conf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key', <secret_key>)
conf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.session.token', <token>)
 
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
df2 = spark.read.format("csv").load('s3a://<some_path_to_a_file>')
df2.show()
df2.createOrReplacementTempView("table1")
dfsql = spark.sql("select * from table1")
dfsql.show()
```